# Java Formattable Interface and printf parameters

Tags: java

I am implementing the formatTo() method of the Formattable interface inside a class. and Then I am using it with printf() arguments like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        BankAccount1 bankAccount = new BankAccount1(1234.12) ;

        //Don't understand this code
        System.out.printf("%s %10S.\n", "Balance = ", bankAccount) ;
}
class BankAccount implements Formattable
{

    public void formatTo(Formatter formatter, int flags, int width, int precision)
    {

        Appendable appendable = formatter.out() ;
        String balanceString = "" + balance ;


        for (int i = balanceString.length() ; i < width ; i++)
        balanceString = "$" + balanceString ;

        try {

            //tells appendable to append balanceString to printf's string
            appendable.append(balanceString) ;

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(0) ;
        }

    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Balance =  $$$1234.12.
```

My question is that on the line:

```
System.out.printf("%s %10S.\n", "Balance = ", bankAccount) ;
```

I know %s is for string, but what is "%10S.\n" doing? Moreover in "%10S.\n" why "%10S" why the capital S, what does it represents?

Comment: You wrote this code, right? Why did **you** use a capital `S` and not a lower case char? Also you shouldn't use `/n` with `printf` but rather the platform independent `%n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `BankAccount Class` has implements `Formattable interface`,

Now,

> Syntax of printf looks likewise,

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

now, let me elaborate it,

`%10` means total `width` of the output will be 10. `(in java, string length = 10)`

now for S or s means,

> If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg
>   implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the
>   result is obtained by invoking arg.toString().

and last end by `.` which will reflect into out-put by .(dot)

so finally, output : `$$$1234.12.` with 10-length(`$$$1234.12`) with dot ended.

Here, interesting is S - that will call formatTo of BankAccount, as i mentioned above.